# NotificationListenerService cancelNotification won't work

Tags: android, service, notifications, statusbar

I implemented a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and am having trouble getting cancelNotification(). I get all the notifications from getActiveNotifications() (successfully retrieving an array of current notifications) and for some reason when I call getTag() on each [StatusBarNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) it always returns null. Passing null as the tag does not appear to work as the notifications are never removed. Any ideas?

Comment: Calling getTag on the StatusBarNotification received in onNotificationPosted also only returns null

Comment: did you find how to remove the notifications? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did find my issue. I was sending the cancel notification information through broadcast receiver. This meant the tag I was sending to cancelNotification was string that was "null" rather than really null. Added an if check to fix and it all works happily now.